# no appropriate default constructor available error with initializer list

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inheritance, constructor, initializer-list

For some reason I'm getting the no default constructor error even though I'm using a member initializer. What am I doing wrong?

A minimal example,

a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"


a::a(int x, int y, int z):x(x),y(y),z(z)
{
}
```

a.h

```
class a
{
public:
    a(int x, int y, int z);

private:
    int x, y, z;
};
```

b.cpp

```
#include "b.h"


b::b()
    :ao(1,2,3)
{
}
```

b.h

```
#include "a.h"

class b: public a
{
public:
    b();

private:
    a ao;
};
```

Comment: You're not explicitly initialising the base `a`, only the member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `b` has two `a` objects in it: one is called `ao` and is a member variable, and the other is the one `b` is inherited from. You're already initializing `ao` explicitly in the initializer list, but you're not initializing `b`'s parent. You can do this by inserting `a(4,5,6),` in the initializer list immediately before `ao(1,2,3)`.